# Is there a way to prevent Eclipse from opening the browser when starting a Web application?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications

Ahoy!

I was wondering if there's a way to configure eclipse not to open the browser (internal or external, doesn't matter) when the user selects Run As > Run or server in a specific (or any) web project.

Couldn't find that option...

Comment: There is nothing like this but do you really want such feature in your eclipse?

Comment: I sure do. Every time it opens a new tab in the browser, but sometimes I just want to keep working on my current tab.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No there is not. The way to do this is not click on the apllication and run as, but to click on your server and launch it(and deploy your application). Then you will get rid of browser opening.

Answer (score 45):

On Eclipse Juno through Oxygen, change the preferences (Window->Preferences->General->Web Browser) to add a new external web browser and set it's location as "`/bin/true`" (under UNIX), "`/usr/bin/true`" (under Mac OS Yosemite through Mojave), or "`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`" with parameter "`/c`" (under Windows). Then set this as the default browser.

After this, whenever you "Run on server", Eclipse will spawn this command  (which immediately succeeds) instead of touching your browser.

This isn't a per-project setting though.

Comment: For Windows users who want to do something similar you can set location to "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" and put /c in the parameters.

Comment: In Mac OSX Yosemite, it is /usr/bin/true

Comment: @mockobject mockobject, thanks it works like a charm

Comment: Thanks! I must have clicked accidentally somewhere, then Eclipse started to open links in its internal bwrowser, even those to GitLab Merge Requests.

Answer (score 5):

If you run the server from the server view it won't open the browser.

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering the same question

Instead of clicking the run button [image]

try press Relaunch [image: Relaunch]

(I'm on STS)

Answer (score 2):

You should try this:

In MyEclipse, change the preferences (Window->Preferences->General->Web Browser) check radio button (use external web browser) and click on new to add a new external web browser and set it's location of your browser and enter name (as your choice), then click on ok.

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed this issue for me. You should do the following:
Create a file null.bat that contains something like "@echo off". It doesn't really matter where you put it.

Go to Eclipse=>Preferences=>General=>Web Browser, check "Use external web browser". Create a new external Web broswer.
Name it something and
point the Location to where you stored your null.bat

That way Eclipse runs your null.bat and does nothing :)

Answer (score 0):

In latest version of Eclipse 2022-03 or later
Simply Click on Window--->Web Browser--->Internal Web Browser.
You can select other browser too as per your wish.