# Run Webapplication in Eclipse: don't open new Browser tab

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, browser, tabs

I develop a Vaadin Application with Eclipse and two things are driving me crazy:

- whenever I hit CTRL+F11 (run), Eclipse opens a new Browser tab, even if I already have one (or 50) of that Application open
- if I don't have the project selected in the project explorer but some class instead, Eclipse opens "http://localhost:8080/WEB-INF/classes/org/somepackage/MyClass.java" instead, which does not run the Application but gives me an error

Those two things don't make it impossible for me but because they occur so frequently they are a big annoyance for my work so I would be really glad if someone could tell me how to fix this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to prevent Eclipse from opening the browser when starting a Web application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041975/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-eclipse-from-opening-the-browser-when-starting-a-web-a)

Comment: To prevent Eclipse from opening browser windows at all (instead manually loading the URL in your normal browser, which I prefer), see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17193998/193435